# LDAP Laravel database query

Tags: laravel, database, ldap

I understand that LDAP was used here. I have a problem with Laravel. There is a JSON file in the LDAP directory, and I need to extract a key from it and then use it to perform a database query. Is it possible to do this in LDAP?

I tried adding an attribute to the model and adding it to the request. Nothing succeeded.

Comment: share any useful code that we can help with

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.